# ROW START and ROW END in SQL Server temporal tables

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

I've been using SQL Server system-versioned temporal tables for a while now, and they seem to work really well. I need to write a query with a self-join to the subsequent version of the record, and I'm not sure I'm doing it right.

I need to find cases where a value changed from one value to another, say from "A" to "B" specifically.

Here's my query

```
SELECT t1.Id,
       t1.MyValue OldValue,  
       c2.MyValue NewValue,  
       t2.ValidFrom DateChanged  
FROM MyTable FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL t1  
JOIN MyTable FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL t2 ON t2.Id = t1.Id AND t2.ValidFrom = t1.ValidTo  
WHERE t1.MyValue = 'A'  
AND t2.MyValue = 'B';
```

"Id" is the primary key and "ValidFrom" and "ValidTo" are the ROW START and ROW END columns.

This seems to work, but I'm wondering about the reliability of that join `t2.ValidFrom = t1.ValidTo`

- Is it always the case that the subsequent record in the history has ValidFrom exactly equal to ValidTo of the previous record? Are there ever gaps in the sequence?
- Is there any possibility of two records in the history table having the same ValidFrom date?

Comment: Why do you need a self-join, why not just use `LEAD` or `LAG`?

Comment: *"Is it always the case that the subsequent record in the history has ValidFrom exactly equal to ValidTo of the previous record? Are there ever gaps in the sequence?"* - For updates yes, but this is not enforced by `PERIOD FOR` because there are valid reasons for not matching. If a record is deleted, then re-inserted the end date of the deleted record would not match the start date of the inserted record.

Comment: *"Is there any possibility of two records in the history table having the same ValidFrom date?"* - Yes - if you perform a non-deterministic update that updates the same row twice that will generate two history records, but one will have an end date that matches the start date, but that will be filtered out automatically by `FOR SYSTEM_TIME` so should not be an issue for your query. There is no possibility of two "valid" records with the same start date

Comment: @GarethD A single `UPDATE` or `MERGE` statement cannot update the same row twice. What can happen is that two statements in the same transaction happen, where `ROW START` is fixed at the beginning of the transaction.

Comment: @Charlieface Yes fair, I skim read the documentation and pretty much stopped reading after this part *"if you perform multiple updates on the same primary key"*, at which point I stopped reading I drew a conclusion in my head that this would be from a non-deterministic update as a result of a join with each of the possibilities being recorded. I should have read/thought further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it always the case that the subsequent record in the history has `ValidFrom` exactly equal to `ValidTo` of the previous record? Are there ever gaps in the sequence?

That depends on what you mean by "the previous record". If you only ever do `UPDATE` rather than `DELETE` and `INSERT` then yes that will be the case.

But you could delete and reinsert the data, in which case it won't line up. Whether that's what you want to know about is your decision.

> Is there any possibility of two records in the history table having the same `ValidFrom` date?

If you make two updates on the same row within the same transaction then this could happen. The `ValidFrom` is calculated only once at the beginning of the transaction for all rows.

Using `FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL`, no it's not possible, because [it uses a filter `ValidFrom <> ValidTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16#code-try-1) automatically, thereby excluding such rows. The issue only appears if you query the history table directly.

---

A safer and more efficient option to get the next value is to just use `LAG` or `LEAD`. Do note that in the case of duplicate `ValidFrom` you will get non-deterministic results (if you query the history table directly), but it will still be a single row.

```sql
SELECT
  t.Id,
  t.OldMyValue AS OldValue,  
  t.MyValue AS NewValue,  
  t.ValidFrom AS DateChanged  
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      LAG(t.MyValue) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Id ORDER BY t.ValidFrom) AS OldMyValue
    FROM MyTable FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL t
) t
WHERE t.MyValue = 'B'
  AND t.OldMyValue = 'A';
```

Comment: I'm not sure it would get non-deterministic results would it? Since `FOR SYSTEM_TIME` will remove any records with a period of validity with zero duration, so wouldn't it only be nondeterministic if querying the history table directly? https://dbfiddle.uk/FBtVsfKe

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. "`FOR SYSTEM_TIME` filters out rows that have a period of validity with zero duration `(ValidFrom = ValidTo)`." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16#how-do-i-query-temporal-data so in theory the results should have been the same. I note that the query plan has a `ValidFrom <> ValidTo` predicate, so it seems this is by design.